# Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 1920 when using ffi-napi library to call dll library in electron project

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I try to call the `dll` file using the `ffi-napi` library in my electron project, the command prompt gives me an error of 1920, but when I call it from the root directory it works fine. Why is this so, is my authority not enough, through the administrator is the same error

**Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 1920
at new DynamicLibrary (D:\zyh\test\electron\demo\node_modules@lwahonen\ffi-napi\lib\dynamic_library.js:73:11)
at Object.Library (D:\zyh\test\electron\demo\node_modules@lwahonen\ffi-napi\lib\library.js:47:10)
at D:\zyh\test\electron\demo\main.js:64:21
at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:189:579
at EventEmitter. (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:161:11327)
at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28)**

window11
@lwahonen/ffi-napi": "^4.0.12",
@lwahonen/ref-napi": "^4.0.8",
electron:v20.0.0
nodejs:17.9.1

I tried running Powershell as an administrator and giving my `dll` full control to everyone. Changing the read path to an absolute path, but it didn't work

```js
const ffi = require('@lwahonen/ffi-napi');
const ref = require('@lwahonen/ref-napi')
const StructType = require('ref-struct-napi');
let myDll
let csptcabsPtr
// 主进程监听调用dll点击
ipcMain.handle('SptcTest', (event, msg) => {
  //定义 T_RSLT_DATA 结构体
  const T_RSLT_DATA = StructType({
    'iLesTypeL': 'int',
    'iLesTypeR': 'int',
    'fRDistance': 'float',
    'fLDistance': 'float',
    'fDSphereL': 'float',
    'fDSphereR': 'float',
    'fDCyldL': 'float',
    'fDCyldR': 'float',
    'fAxisL': 'float',
    'fAxisR': 'float',
    'fDistance': 'float',
    'fUpSphL': 'float',
    'fUpSphR': 'float',
    'fLowSphL': 'float',
    'fLowSphR': 'float',
    'fAddL': 'float',
    'fAddR': 'float',
    'fSCyldL': 'float',
    'fSCyldR': 'float',
    'fSAxisL': 'float',
    'fSAxisR': 'float',
    'fSDistanceUp': 'float',
    'fSDistanceLow': 'float',
    'fSDistance': 'float'
  });
  const T_UUID_DATA = StructType({
    'sUuid': 'string',
    'sDeviceNumber': 'string'
  });
  try {
    // 定义 DLL 导出函数
    myDll = ffi.Library('E:/test/resources/SptcTest.dll', {
      'GetSptcTestObj': ['pointer', []], 
      'MultiTest': [T_RSLT_DATA, ['pointer']], 
      'PalTest': [T_RSLT_DATA, ['pointer']], 
      'DataTest': [T_RSLT_DATA, ['pointer']],
      'DataTest_str': [T_RSLT_DATA, ['pointer', 'string']], 
      'PalDataTest': [T_RSLT_DATA, ['pointer']],
      'PalDataTest_str': [T_RSLT_DATA, ['pointer', 'string']],
      'Calibdataget': ['void', ['pointer']], 
      'DelSptcTestObj': ['void', ['pointer']], 
      'CloseDoor': ['void', ['pointer']], 
      'OpenDoor': ['void', ['pointer']], 
      'InitGT': ['void', ['pointer']], 
      'GetUIID': [T_UUID_DATA, ['pointer']] 
    });
    let GetSptcTestObj = function() {
    
      win.webContents.send('loading')

      csptcabsPtr = myDll.GetSptcTestObj()
      if (csptcabsPtr) {
        win.webContents.send('GetSptcTestObj')
      }
    }


    switch (msg) {
      case 'GetSptcTestObj':
        if (!csptcabsPtr) {
          GetSptcTestObj()
        }
        break;
      case 'OpenDoor':
        console.log('kaimeng');
        myDll.OpenDoor(csptcabsPtr)
        break;
      case 'CloseDoor':
        myDll.CloseDoor(csptcabsPtr);
        break;
      case 'MultiTest':
        const MultiTestData = myDll.MultiTest(csptcabsPtr);
        const MultiTestResult = ref.get(MultiTestData, 0, T_RSLT_DATA);
        const MultiTestJsonResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MultiTestResult));
        console.log('MultiTest');
        return MultiTestJsonResult
      case 'PalTest':
        const PalTestData = myDll.PalTest(csptcabsPtr);
        const PalTestResult = ref.get(PalTestData, 0, T_RSLT_DATA);
        const PalTestJsonResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(PalTestResult));
        console.log('PalTest');
        return PalTestJsonResult
      case 'InitGT':
        myDll.InitGT(csptcabsPtr)
        break;
      case 'GetUIID':
        console.log('huoqu id');
        const structUiidData = myDll.GetUIID(csptcabsPtr);
        const jsonResult = ref.get(structUiidData, 0, T_UUID_DATA);
        const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonResult));
        return result
      default:
        break;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

It seems like this error will occur whenever you're not in the root directory

Comment: Hi, please provide the code using the code blocks (```), instead of images of the code